# Cannot send data to database after update data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a newbie in using flutter, so this time I want to explain my problem. I created a data update form, when I want to update the data but the data cannot be updated and sent to the database, can friends here help solve my problem? Here is the source code snippet that I made. Thank you all friends. I hope that friends can also understand my question :)

**edit_nasabah.dart**

```
class EditNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  Nasabah nasabah;
  EditNasabah({this.nasabah});
  @override
  _EditNasabahState createState() => _EditNasabahState(this.nasabah);
}

class _EditNasabahState extends State<EditNasabah> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final Nasabah nasabah;
  _EditNasabahState(this.nasabah);
  bool _secureText = true;
  String nama_debitur, alamat, no_telp, no_ktp, no_selular;

  showHide() {
    setState(() {
      _secureText = !_secureText;
    });
  }

  _showMsg(msg) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(msg),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Edit Data"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Card(
                child: Column(

                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.info, size: 50),
                      title: Text('Edit Form Debitur'),
                      subtitle: Text('Silahkan edit sesuai form dibawah ini'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Nama Debitur',
                        ),
                        validator: (nameValue) {
                          if (nameValue.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your full name';
                          }
                          nasabah.nama_debitur = nameValue;
                          return null;
                        },
                        initialValue: "${nasabah.nama_debitur}",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Alamat',
                        ),
                        validator: (alamatValue) {
                          if (alamatValue.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your full name';
                          }
                          alamat = alamatValue;
                          return null;
                        },
                      initialValue: "${nasabah.alamat}",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Nomor Telepon',
                        ),
                        validator: (notlpValue) {
                          if (notlpValue.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your full name';
                          }
                          no_telp = notlpValue;
                          return null;
                        },
                      initialValue: "${nasabah.no_telp}",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'NIK',
                        ),
                        validator: (noktpValue) {
                          if (noktpValue.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your full name';
                          }
                          no_ktp = noktpValue;
                          return null;
                        },
                      initialValue: "${nasabah.no_ktp}",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'No Selular',
                        ),
                        validator: (nosllValue) {
                          if (nosllValue.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your full name';
                          }
                          no_selular = nosllValue;
                          return null;
                        },
                      initialValue: "${nasabah.no_selular}",
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _update();
                          }
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Color(0xff374ABE), Color(0xff64B6FF)],
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          child: Container(
                            constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              _isLoading? 'Proccessing..' : 'Simpan',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

This is a function to send data to the database

```
 void _update() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    var data = {nasabah.nama_debitur,nasabah.alamat,nasabah.no_telp,nasabah.no_ktp,nasabah.no_selular};
    print(data);

    var res = await Network().updateData(data, 'mstdebitur');
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('mstdebitur', json.encode(body['mstdebitur']));

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Berhasil Disimpan'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));

    } else {
      if (body['message']['nama_debitur'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['nama_debitur'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['alamat'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['alamat'][0].toString());
      } else if (body['message']['no_telp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_telp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_ktp'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_ktp'][0].toString());
      }
      else if (body['message']['no_selular'] != null) {
        _showMsg(body['message']['no_selular'][0].toString());
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text("Gagal")));
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

**api.dart**

```
updateData(apiURL, id) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
    await _getToken();
    return await http.put(
      fullUrl,
      headers: _setHeaders(),
    );
  }
```

**nasabah_service.dart**

```
  static Future<List<Nasabah>> updateUser(id) async {
    final response = await Network().updateData(baseUrl, id,);
    List<Nasabah> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list;
  }
```

I hope friends can help me.

Answer (score 0):

use TextEditingController for each `TextFormField`1

create **text controller** variable:

```
  final TextEditingController _nama_debiturController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _alamatController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_telpController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_ktpController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _no_selularController = TextEditingController();
```

you can init value form textController in `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nama_debiturController.text = "hel;lo";
    _alamatController.text = "Hi";
    _no_telpController.text = "He";
  }
```

And edit your `TextFormField` widget code:

- remove `initialValue: ,`
- add `controller: ,`

Example:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  controller: _nama_debiturController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Nama Debitur',
  ),
  validator: (nameValue) {
  if (nameValue!.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please enter your full name';
  }
  nasabah.nama_debitur = nameValue;
    return null;
  },
),
```

in your `_update()`

```
void _update() async {

    var data = {
      _nama_debiturController.text,
      _alamatController.text,
      _no_telpController.text,
      _no_ktpController.text,
      _no_selularController.text
    };
    print(data);
  }
```

your **Form**:

```
Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _nama_debiturController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Nama Debitur',
                      ),
                      validator: (nameValue) {
                        if (nameValue!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        nasabah.nama_debitur = nameValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _alamatController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Alamat',
                      ),
                      validator: (alamatValue) {
                        if (alamatValue!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        alamat = alamatValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_telpController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Nomor Telepon',
                      ),
                      validator: (notlpValue) {
                        if (notlpValue!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        no_telp = notlpValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_ktpController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'NIK',
                      ),
                      validator: (noktpValue) {
                        if (noktpValue!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        no_ktp = noktpValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _no_selularController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'No Selular',
                      ),
                      validator: (nosllValue) {
                        if (nosllValue!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your full name';
                        }
                        no_selular = nosllValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            _update();
                          }
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Color(0xff374ABE), Color(0xff64B6FF)],
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          child: Container(
                            constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              _isLoading? 'Proccessing..' : 'Simpan',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

You are missing body of data in `put` method

```
updateData(apiURL, id, Map<String, String> data ) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
    await _getToken();
    return await http.put(
      fullUrl,
      headers: _setHeaders(),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
    );
  }
```

**your data**

```
Map<String, String> data = {
      "body1" : _nama_debiturController.text,
      "body1": _alamatController.text,
      "body1": _no_telpController.text,
      "body1" : _no_ktpController.text,
      "body1" : _no_selularController.text
    };
    print(data);

    var res = await Network().updateData(data, 'mstdebitur', data);
```

Comment: get Error : E/flutter ( 6939): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 6939): #0      Network.updateData (package:flutter_auth/network/api.dart:31:26)
E/flutter ( 6939): #1      _EditNasabahState._update (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_nasabah.dart:217:31)
E/flutter ( 6939): #2      _EditNasabahState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_nasabah.dart:167:29)

Comment: this error come from api request, i think you need check you logic code, I just can help you print data of textfield

Comment: this code in this part API.DART, can you help to check ?

Comment: I updated, try again @AzmiBadhi'uzZaman

Comment: after I changed there was an error in nasabah_service.dart there is an error in the final response = await Network().updateData(baseUrl, id,); How to solve this error? @Saitoh Akira

Comment: then there is still an error

E/flutter ( 6939): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 6939): #0      Network.updateData (package:flutter_auth/network/api.dart:31:26)
E/flutter ( 6939): #1      _EditNasabahState._update (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_nasabah.dart:217:31)
E/flutter ( 6939): #2      _EditNasabahState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/edit_nasabah.dart:167:29)